# Sometimes can't get FB id with JS API

Tags: javascript, facebook

In about 0.3% of users, I can't get their FB ID with JS API. On some occasions I have gotten it before for those users. What could be the cause of this and any ideas on how to fix it?

As far as I know most of those users were on Windows and using firefox.

My code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId : "xxxx",
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml : true,
        oauth : true
    });
    FB.Canvas.setSize({width:$("#mainbody").outerWidth(),height:$("#mainbody").outerHeight()});
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if(response.authResponse){
            if(response.authResponse.userID){
                fbId = response.authResponse.userID;
                $("#hiddenFbId").val(fbId);
                setSession();
            }
        }
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api(
                "/me?locale=et_EE",
                function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    fbName = response['name'];
                    fbId = response['id'];
                    $("#hiddenFbId").val(fbId);
                    fbEmail = response['email'];
                    setSession();
                }
            });
        } else {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    if(response.authResponse.userID){
                        fbId = response.authResponse.userID;
                        $("#hiddenFbId").val(fbId);
                        setSession();
                    }
                    FB.api(
                        "/me?locale=et_EE",
                        function (response) {
                        if (response && !response.error) {
                            fbName = response['name'];
                            fbId = response['id'];
                            $("#hiddenFbId").val(fbId);
                            fbEmail = response['email'];
                            setSession();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    fbDenied = true;
                }
            }, {
                scope : 'public_profile,email,user_likes'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never call FB.login in the asynchronous (!) callback function of FB.getLoginStatus. Some browsers block the login popup if you do that, you always need to call FB.login on user interaction - and calling it on page load is a bad idea anyway. Don´t force the user to authorize your App right when they enter your App and before they know what your App is about.

- FB.getLoginStatus on page load to refresh the User Token and to check if the user is authorized
- FB.login on mouse click

It is also easier that way to remove some redundant code and move your FB.api call to a function.

It may or may not solve your problem, but it´s definitely important and a commong source of errors.

Comment: FB.login shouldn't be a problem because the app is in a FB page tab and can't be accessed when not logged in. I'll still try moving login to click.

Comment: that´s not the point and it does not matter - because page tabs CAN be accessed when not logged in. FB.login should ALWAYS be called on user interaction.